# Using FindView in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to use:

```
var viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, myViewName, null);
```

as part of a process to render the contents of a view to send nice formatted emails. I'm using it inside an Orchard Controller. I have used similar code outside of Orchard in an MVC project and it works fine.

However in Orchard running this code fails to find the view I'm looking for and returns a view engine result that has searched 0 locations.

viewEngineResult has the following values after it is called:

- SearchedLocations: Count = 0,
- View: null,
- ViewEngine: null

Is there a reason this doesn't work in Orchard and is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll want to take a close look at Orchard.Framework/Mvc/ViewEngines, in particular IViewEngineProvider and ThemeAwareViewEngine. There's a lot more going on when in Orchard, such as themes, multi-tenancy, and a richer environment in general that may be needed to make this work.
What's likely happening here is that the view engines don't have enough information to resolve a view and thus opt out of the chain. You might want to put a breakpoint into ThemeAwareViewEngine.FindView, and then inspect the private dependency fields of that class. I wouldn't be surprised if they were null, because getting to FindView through statics will probably not allow dependency injection to do its stuff properly.
Then again I'm just guessing.

Comment: The private dependency fields all seem fine, but it has the current theme set as null, so that seems to be lost. I tried adding ~/ and giving a full path to my view which made it search in the right place using BareEngines, but it still didn't find the view. Is there a way to hook into part templates instead and use those to get content for my email?

Comment: Did you try to get an instance of IViewEngineProvider injected into your own code and start from there, instead of using the static calls into the regular MVC API?

Comment: Seem to be getting closer now. I'm using an injected IViewEngineProvider to create a module view engine. This needs a CreateModulesViewEngineParams object that contains a collection of Virtual Paths. Is there a way to get that, or have I taken a wrong turn.

Comment: I'm not sure. Did you try to track existing usage of that?

Comment: I've not found a really clear usage example yet, but I'll keep digging and fiddling. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is based on the advise given me by Bertrand, but I wanted to bring it together with what I'd discovered.

To be able to use FindPartialView I needed to inject an instance of IViewEngineProvider into my controller.

I then used the following code to resolve and render a view:

```
private String RenderView(String viewName, object model)
{
    var paths = new List<string>(); // This can just be an empty list and it still finds it.
    var viewEngine = _viewEngineProvider.CreateModulesViewEngine(new CreateModulesViewEngineParams {VirtualPaths = paths});
    var viewResult = viewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName, false);

    if (viewResult.View == null) {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't find view " + viewName);
    }

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary {Model = model};

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly does not work in Orchard 1.10.1, empty `paths` causing an exception.

Comment: I believe you can simply inject `IThemeAwareViewEngine` and use its `FindPartialView` method.