# Can I render all zones to an HTML string in a controller method

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to render the HTML for a content item to a string from within a controller action.  Technically I just want to get the "body" part of it without any header/footer stuff.  I want to do this so I can get a content item rendering the way I want once, and then display it as a normal orchard page OR by requesting the HTML for the content item via ajax to display it in a div in a JavaScript app.  I don't want to have to manually render everything in the JavaScript as that would be duplicating the layout logic I already did.  I want to re-use the bulk of the server side rendering so any changes are reflected in my normal orchard page and my JavaScript page.  I've been digging into the code and searching everywhere and have gotten close but not all the way there.

I found these:

[How to render shape to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951605/how-to-render-shape-to-string)

[Using FindView in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983372/using-findview-in-orchard)

In my controller I have:

var shape = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);

Using either of the two methods above, I can render that shape to an HTML string in my controller.  All was golden.  I was getting the body of that page and using it in JS.  Then, I changed a placement file:

<Place Parts_Common_Body="Content:1" />

was changed to:

<Place Parts_Common_Body="/AsideFirst:1" />

The body moved where I wanted it (AsideFirst) in my normal Orchard page but disappeared from the HTML retrieved using the two methods above.

If I look at shape.Content.Items after the BuildDisplay call, I can see the item for the body is no longer there...  why is it not rendering all the zones?  Or, I guess a more specific question is why is the BuildDisplay method not building the complete shape?  Is there a way I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a million different things and eventually got this working.  Not sure I totally get it yet, but I think the problem had to do with the fact that I was using shape.Content and I'd moved stuff out of the Content zone.  And maybe when I was looking at what the BuildDisplay method was returning I was just not looking at some newly created zone that actually did had the stuff I thought was missing.  Clearly I need to learn more about zones and shapes...  Anyway, I have a new zone called "MainInfo" now that I created in a placement file.  I get a MainInfo property on the main shape returned form BuildDisplay and pass shape.MainInfo to the view rendering code and all seems to be working well now.